# Structuring a book

Tags: listings, best-practices, book-design

I am writing some notes for my CS classmates, and I am interested in the following areas:

- Does it follow good code practises?
- Is the book / notes / document well structured?
- Is there any 'unforgivable' code fragment?
- Do I use correctly figure environments?
- Are `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` correctly placed?
- Anything else to improve?

I'll show you the code of the main file and the code of a chapter. The chapter is not entirely genuine, so, do not scare if English is mixed with [Catalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_language). I just invented it in order to allow you to analyse the structure of my chapters (each chapter has got the same structure: algorithm explanation + last section = *Codes in C++* with `lstlisting`s with C++ code). I use several theorem boxes such as `defi` (definition), `conv` (convention) and `prob` (problem).

I have uploaded the generated PDF [in my personal Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/34mqp966my8dv5n/notes.pdf?dl=0) (and [in an 3rd party web](https://ufile.io/7fd82)), so you can have a look to all the document.

Here is the code of file `notes.tex`, the main file.

```
% Compile with pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, titlepage]{book}

% LINKS
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!60!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!30!black}
}


% PAGE STRUCTURE
\usepackage{geometry}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % Just chapters and sections


% TYPOGRAPHY
% Encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Math fonts
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% Text fonts
\usepackage{mathpazo}    % Palatino fallback
\usepackage{newtxtext}   % ~Times for text
\usepackage{newtxmath}   % ~Times for math
\usepackage{inconsolata} % Monospaced font

% Text tricks
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}


% LANGUAGE
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\addto\captionscatalan{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Tema}}


% THEOREMS
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{leftline=false, rightline=false, linecolor=gray,
    linewidth=1pt, skipabove=\topskip, skipbelow=\topskip,
    innerleftmargin=0, innerrightmargin=0}
\newmdtheoremenv{prob}{Problem}
\newmdtheoremenv{defi}{Theorem}
\newmdtheoremenv{conv}{Convention}


% FIGURES
% Images
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Just demo for the question

% Code
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language          = C++,
    columns           = fullflexible,
    identifierstyle   = \itshape,
    keywordstyle      = \bfseries\color{blue!50!black},
    frame             = tb,
    rulecolor         = \color{blue!20!black},
    framerule         = 1pt,
    showstringspaces  = false,
    tabsize           = 4,
    morekeywords      = {pair, vector, list, set, graph, stack,
                         queue, priority_queue, iterator, const_iterator},
    framexleftmargin  = 1em,
    framexrightmargin = 1em,
    literate          = {<=}{{$\leq$ }}1 
                        {>=}{{$\geq$ }}1 
                        {!=}{{$\neq$ }}1    % transform {<=, >=, !=} to {≤, ≥, ≠}.
}


% MY COMMANDS
% Math shortcuts
\renewcommand{\o}{\ensuremath{\mathrm o}}           % Little-o notation
\renewcommand{\O}{\ensuremath{\mathrm O}}           % Big-o notation
\newcommand{\twodots}{\mathinner{\ldotp \ldotp}}    % Use in subvectors v[i..j]


% TITLE
% First page decoration
\newcommand{\titledecoration}{%
    {\fontsize{72}{70}\selectfont\color{gray}$\Theta(n \log n)$}\\[5em]
}

% Title, author, date
\title{\titledecoration%
    A Very Important Subject}
\author{My Name and Surname}
\date{Fall Semester (2016--17)\\
    My City Schools of Informatics (MCSI)\\
    Worldwide University of the Univers (WUU)}

% I just include this package for this question!!
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    % FIRST PAGES
    \frontmatter

    % First page: title
    \newgeometry{margin=1.5in}
    \maketitle
    \restoregeometry

    % Second page: copyright
    \null\vfill
    \includegraphics{copy.png}

    All rights reserved. No part of this book may be
    reproduced in any form or by any electronic... % etcetera

    \url{https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/deed.ca}

    % Preface
    \chapter{Prefaci}

    \textbf{Why do I write these notes?}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item ...
        \item ...
        \item ...
    \end{itemize}

    \textbf{Sources and bibliography}
    % Ok, I should use \bibliography, but I just
    % have to cite a few sources (4 or 5).
    \begin{itemize}
        \item ...
        \item ...
        \item ...
        \item ...
    \end{itemize}

    \textbf{Book structure}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item ...
        \item ...
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{description}
        \item[Contact mail] \ 

        \href{mailto:my@email.com}{my@email.com}
    \end{description}

    % toc
    \tableofcontents

    % CHAPTERS
    \mainmatter
    \include{cap1}
    \include{cap2}
    \include{cap3}
    % and so on

\end{document}
```

And here is the code of a single chapter, let's say `cap1.tex`. I strongly suggest you to compare it with the PDF that I had linked for you before. Also, there is a lot of dummy text extracted from the real document, so you can scan it by just searching the comments (search `%` symbol) with your browser. They are set on purpose.

```
\chapter{Asymptotic notation}

\section{Cost in time and space}
\lipsum[4-6]

\section{Cas pitjor, millor i mitjà}
Trobar la funció $T$ anterior pot ser complicat. Ens interessarem només per aquells conjunts d'entrades que tinguin mida $n$.

% Use of definition

\begin{defi}
    Sigui $\mathcal A_n$ el conjunt d'entrades de mida $n$ i sigui $T_n: \mathcal A_n \to \mathbb R$ la funció $T$ restringida a $\mathcal A_n$. Els costos en cas pitjor, millor i mitjà es defineixen com segueix.

    \begin{description}
        \item[Cost en cas pitjor] $T_\text{pitjor}(n) = \max \{T_n(\alpha) \colon \alpha \in \mathcal A_n\}$
        \item[Cost en cas millor] $T_\text{millor}(n) = \min \{T_n(\alpha) \colon \alpha \in \mathcal A_n\}$
        \item[Cost en cas mitjà] $T_\text{mitjà}(n) = \sum_{\alpha \in \mathcal A_n} [ \Pr(\alpha) \cdot T_n (\alpha) ]$, on $\Pr(\alpha)$ és la probabilitat d'ocurrència de l'entrada $\alpha$.
    \end{description}
\end{defi}

\lipsum[8]

\section{Convencions}
Tot i que $\O,$ $\dots$, $\omega$ són \textit{conjunts} de funcions, i, donada una funció $f\colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$, s'ha d'escriure $f \in \O(g)$, per a certa funció $g$, sovint no es fa servir aquesta notació.

% Use of convention

\begin{conv}
    Siguin $f$ i $g$ funcions i $X$ qualsevol dels conjunts $\O$, $\dots$, $\omega$. Entenem que l'abús de notació $f = X(g)$ significa $f \in X(g)$.

    Per tant, podem escriure $3n^2 = \Theta(n^2)$, $n \log n = \omega (100 n)$, etc. Aquesta convenció, però, no és commutativa: es pot dir $n = \O(n^2)$, però no té cap sentit escriure $\O(n^3) = 10n^2 - 5n$.
\end{conv}

En fórmules de recurrència, de vegades necessitarem escriure expressions com
\[ T(n) = T(n/2) + \Theta(1) \]
Aquest $\Theta(1)$ s'ha d'entendre com ``qualsevol funció $f(n)$ tal que $f = \Theta(1)$''.

\begin{conv}
    Podem interpretar $f \star X(g)$ com ``$f \star h$, per a qualsevol funció $h$ tal que $h = X(g)$'', on $\star$ és qualsevol operador binari i $X$ és qualsevol dels conjunts $\O, \dots, \omega$.
\end{conv}

\section{\textit{Quicksort}} % Quicksort is a foreign term in catalan
El problema és el d'ordenar un vector $v$ de mida $n$ (vegeu el problema \ref{prob:ordenar}).

Les fases de dividir i vèncer són:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \textit{Divisió}: particionar $v$ en dos subvectors no buits $v_l$ i $v_r$ de la següent manera.

    Sigui $0 \leq i < n$. Volem trobar l'índex $i$ de $v$ tal que $v_l = v[0 \twodots i]$, $v_r = v[i+1 \twodots n-1]$, i tot element de $v_l$ és menor o igual que tot element de $v_r$. És a dir, \[\forall a \in [0, i] \text{ i } \forall b\in[i+1, n-1]\text{, es verifica que } v[a] \leq v[b]\]

    La primera implementació d'aquest procediment (\textit{partició}) la va inventar en C. A. R. Hoare. Es fa escollint un pivot (per exemple, $v[0]$) i comparant la resta d'elements amb aquest.
    \item \textit{Resolució}: ordenar recursivament $v_l$ i $v_r$
    \item \textit{Combinació}: atès que $v_l$ i $v_r$ estan ordenats, per ordenar $v$ no cal fer res.
\end{enumerate}

% Reference to a full-page figure

El cost de l'algorisme (vegeu \figurename~\ref{fig:quicksort}) és $\Theta(1)$ per a $n = 1$, i, per a $n \geq 2$:
\[ T(n) = T(k) + T(n-k) + \Theta(n) \]
amb $1 \leq k \leq n-1$.

La solució de la recurrència depèn de $k$:

\begin{description}
    \item[En cas pitjor] $\Theta(n^2)$. És la situació en què $k = 1$; la partició ha estat molt dolenta: hem particionat $v$ en un subvector amb 1 element i en un altre subvector amb els $n-1$ elements restants. És el cas en què el vector d'entrada ja està ordenat (creixentment o decreixent).
    \item[En cas millor] $\Theta(n \log n)$. És la solució de la recurrència amb $k = 2$. Intuïtivament, $k = 2$ proporciona la millor partició: $v_l$ i $v_r$ tenen, ambdós com a molt $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ elements; $v$ es parteix per la meitat. 
    \item[En cas mitjà] $\Theta(n \log n)$. Cal suposar una distribució de probabilitat de les entrades. Se sol suposar que totes les permutacions del vector d'entrada són equiprobables i que, per tant, tots els elements tenen la mateixa probabilitat ($1/n$) de ser el pivot.
\end{description}

% A trick to force the figure
% to appear in the following page
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{quicksort.png}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \caption{\label{fig:quicksort}Sorting a vector $v$ using \textit{quicksort}.}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\section{Dummy section}
\lipsum[3-6]


\section{Codes in C++}
% This is a section where I include C++ codes of the algorithms explained
% in the previous sections.
% I also add, here, some implementation tips in the following itemize:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[12]
    \item \lipsum[12]
    % Maybe a crossed reference.
    \item \lipsum[12] See \figurename~\ref{fig:helloworld} for more information.
\end{itemize}

% And, at this point, I use p! and b! in order to get
% a pleasant distribution of code snippets

\begin{figure}[b!]
    % I usually input code by
    % \lstinputlisting{namefile.cc}
    \begin{lstlisting}
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Most difficult code ever" << endl;
}
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{\label{fig:helloworld} The most incredible C++ code ever.}
\end{figure}

% Now an example of my lstlisting options.

\begin{figure}[b!]
    \begin{lstlisting}
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void noncompilant_function() {
    int x = 3;
    double t = 2;
    if (stack<int> != priority_queue<double, int>) {
        for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = b.begin(); it != b.end(); ++it) {
            M[i][j] <= a >= b;
        }
    }
}


// This is a short comment
/* And this is a larger one */
int main() {
    int n, m;
    while (cin >> n >> m) {
        vector<pair<int, int>> amb_lletres;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; --i) {
            for (int j = 0; j >= m; ++j) {
                if (M[i][j] != M[j][i]) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{\label{fig:lstlistexplained} A C++ code that doesn't work at all}
\end{figure}

% And keep inserting figures as the following one:
%\begin{figure}[p]
%   \lstinputlisting{karatsuba.cc}
%   \caption{Implementació en C++ de l'algorisme de Karatsuba
%   \label{fig:karatsuba}}                       
%\end{figure}
```

Any answer will help me.

Comment: Quick note: `hyperref` should be loaded after most packages. If you're curious, there's a pretty elaborate question/answer about that on this site.

Comment: I wouldn't use `\textbf{}` for sectional headers as you do in the preface . Nor would I use manual formatting in the arguments to `\title`, `\author` or `\date`. Don't use `\\ ` to break lines except in `tabular` or `array` or similar. It is OK within a `center` environment, which might apply here. Don't use extensions for images unless you need to (e.g. XeTeX may need this? but not pdfTeX). I would never typeset references manually - not even for a single item. Explicit mark up (`\textbf`, `\textit`, `\vspace` etc.) is used fairly extensively. This is always better avoided if possible.

Comment: even though it seems logical, it's a bad idea to redefine `\O` and `\o`.  these have been defined in all basic implementations to be the scandinavian slashed "o".  if the poor user has to cite a scandinavian author whose name contains one of these letters, a very confusing error could occur, even if utf-8 encoding is used; not all commonly used packages and co-ordinate software have been rebuilt to accommodate it properly.

Comment: By the way, the usual notation for “small o” and “big O” is with italic letters.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to write a great answer to this as a lot of what you are asking about involves a lot of opinion, rather than citable and supportable fact.  Nevertheless, I will give this the best answer I can.

In regards to good code practice, if this is going to be a basis for many documents in the future, you may want to define a new class (`*.cls` file type).  At a minimum, all of the frontmatter you do not plan on changing should be moved into a style (`*.sty` file type).  For greater detail, you can read this [documentation](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2005-3/asknelly/nelly-sty-&-cls.pdf) on the differences between the two.

Also, in terms of text typed into the document, there was an older practice of trying to contain each line of text to 72 characters.  Below is a part of a header I copied from an old template:

```
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------|
% --------------------------- 72 characters ---------------------------|
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

While this limit is not required, I find it helpful to distinguish between my free-form writing while I am creating the document and portions that I have reviewed and completed at least one stage of proofing.

In regards to your code being "pretty," I have not been able to find a style guide for formatting `LaTeX` beyond following general coding practice.  The other notes already provided by @jon and @barbara beeton regarding [order of precedence](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and avoiding single-letter macros are important to remember as well.

Regarding the overall structure of the document, `LaTeX` will do that for you.  It may be easier to maintain the desired structure if you set the file up in the following format:

```
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\include{./TeX_files/Frontpages}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\include{./TeX_files/First_Chapter}
\include{./TeX_files/Next_Chapter}
\include{./TeX_files/Later_Chapter}
\include{./TeX_files/Last_Chapter}

\backmatter
\include{./TeX_files/Appendix_Chapter}
\include{./TeX_files/Bibliography}
\printglossary
\include{./TeX_files/backpages}
\end{document}
```

The format for the `figure` environment should be:

```
\begin{figure}[tbph]
\centering
\includegraphics[size specification]{./Images/Figure}
\caption{Caption of the figure/float}
\label{fig:Figure}
\end{figure}
```

I'm not sure why you would want the information you have to be in a float rather than directly defined, but it is permissible to use the float for purposes other than actual graphics.  The `label` should never be inside the `caption`.  My favorite authoritative source for this type of formatting information can be found here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions